# check if list partially matches other list exactly except for order in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

in javascript, If I have a list, for example:

```
var list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
```

I want to let the user enter a guess(assume the above list is not just 26 letters and 100 or so strings)
and if their guess matches 10 or more of the strings in the list exactly(not including duplicate entries), it will

```
alert("good job! you win");
```

note: I want to do this without using a library(please don't ask why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this (Vanila JavaScript):

```
function matchCount(needles, haystack) {

    var uniqueItems, total = 0;

    uniqueItems = needles.filter(function(value, index, self) { 
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    });

    for(i = 0; i < uniqueItems.length; i++) {
        if(haystack.indexOf(uniqueItems[i]) !== -1) total++;
    }

    return total;
}
```

Then use it like:

```
var list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
var userData = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
var count = matchCount(userData, list);
if(count >= 10) {
    // Contains...
    alert("good job! you win");
}
```

Comment: At first, I was confused why you wrote needle and haystack.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to take care of this.

```
var list = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var input = _.uniq(['b','c','d']); //return only unique values
var min_correct = 3; 
var max_wrong = 3;

var correct_answers = _.intersection(list, input); //contains all correct answers
var incorrect_answers = _.difference(input, list); //contains all incorrect answers

if ( (correct_answers.length >= min_correct) && (incorrect_answers.length <= max_wrong) ) {
  alert ('good job! you win');
}
```